# Knockout mapping plugin and moment.js dates compatibility

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, momentjs

I am getting the following error using [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) when the source data contains [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) dates.

```
TypeError: this._d.getUTCDay is not a function
https://raw.github.com/timrwood/moment/develop/moment.js
Line 1300
```

I have a very simple model as given below. If I use

```
birthDate: new Date(2013, 6, 1)
```

it works fine but if I change it to

```
birthDate: moment().add('days', -5)
```

it throws the above error.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3wQv/)

```
var NS = NS || {};

$(function () {

    NS.ViewModel1 = function (data) {
        var self = this;

        self.firstName = data && data.firstName || "Hello";
        self.lastName = data && data.lastName || "There";
        self.birthDate = data && data.birthDate || new Date(2000, 11, 17);
    };

    var data = {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
        //birthDate: new Date(2013, 6, 1) // Works
        birthDate: moment().add('days', -5)
    };

    var vm1 = new NS.ViewModel1();
    console.log(vm1);
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, vm1);
    console.log(vm1);
    ko.applyBindings(vm1, document.getElementById("observableSection"));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call `moment().add('days', -5)` returns a "moment" object which is a wrapper object around a date and cannot be mapped by the mapping plugin.

What you need is to call `.toDate()` ([doc](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/)) the get back the JavaScipt date or `.format()` ([doc](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)) if you want your date as a formatted string:

So the following should work:

```
var data = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    birthDate: moment().add('days', -5).toDate()
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/K3rBe/)

Comment: Yes it works this way but the same model works without the mapping plugin. [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3wQv/8/). I ran into this when I converted few of the models to use the mapping instead of manually populating the values. I will probably update the models to keep the JS dates instead of moment object.

Comment: It works without the mapping plugin because KO calls `toString()` on the `birthDate` when displaying it in the `text` bindings. You can configure the mapping to "copy over" the `birthDate` instead of the mapping with `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {'copy': ["birthDate"]}, vm1);` http://jsfiddle.net/wgvW9/

Comment: Got it and confirmed in the document as well. Thanks for the followup. Still going thru all the options that this plugin has.